# Getting Error (Unexpected error ; quitting) while registering vb6 exe file on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, com, vb6, typelib

Getting Error (Unexpected error ; quitting) while registering vb6 exe file on windows 7 machine it was running well on windows xp. could some one help me out to solve this error....

Comment: How are you registering it?

Comment: I am registering it by making a bat file <PathOfFile>/Filename.exe /REGSERVER and runs thatbat file by double clicking it.

Comment: Try running your bat file by right clicking and selecting `Run As Admin`

Comment: Done with the same way you are saying but still gettting the same error.. :(

Comment: Do some one have **Answer** to the above question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB6 ActiveX exe - what is the proper registration sequence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821425/vb6-activex-exe-what-is-the-proper-registration-sequence)

Comment: It is possible that you are missing some dependency (msvbvm, perhaps?). Use a tool like depends.exe to check whether all needed dlls are available.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the DCOM Server Process Launcher Service is running. See here for more information: 
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=192360

Answer (score 2):

Run as admin:

This error is caused by insufficient registry permissions for the user that is attempting to build an index.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/966741

Answer (score 0):

Received the same error while trying to register a VB6 class library (MyClass.Exe) in Windows 10 64-bit. I elevated a Command Prompt to Administrator and typed "MyClass.EXE" and it registered.